# EF6 Foreign key with one-to-one relationship and two-way property navigation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I cannot seem to get EF6 to generate a FK when I am using two-way navigation.

Here are my classes (removed some properties for brevity):

```
public class BaseSystem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SystemConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
}

public class SystemConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BaseSystem System { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `SystemConfiguration` table to have a FK reference back to `BaseSystem.Id`.

Here's my fluent API code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemConfiguration>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.System)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Configuration);
```

When I use two-way navigation, this migration is generated which seems to generate the FK at first:

```
CreateTable(
    "MYDB.SYSTEMCONFIGURATION",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0)
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
    .ForeignKey("MYDB.BASESYSTEM", t => t.ID);
```

After noticing that the SQL it generates doesn't include the FK, I removed the `BaseSystem.Configuration` property and the migration generates this:

```
CreateTable(
    "MYDB.SYSTEMCONFIGURATION",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, identity: true),
            SYSTEM_ID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
    .ForeignKey("CISRF.BASESYSTEM", t => t.SYSTEM_ID, cascadeDelete: true);
```

My SQL also generates `"SYSTEM_ID" number(10, 0) not null` as expected which it does not do when I have two-way nav.

What do I need to do to generate the FK on the `SystemConfiguration` table while also still having two-way navigation?

Comment: You can't (EF limitation)- see [Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with **one-to-one** relationship, EF6 uses the `Id` column in the child as the FK to the parent, it won't create a second column for FK because that would be considered **one-to-many** relationship, because that second column would allow a parent `Id` to exist in many child entries, whereas the **PK as FK** wouldn't.

When you removed the `Configuration` property from your **parent class**, EF6 understood your child class had a required `System` as parent, but there was nothing saying it should be one-to-one, so EF6 would treat as a **one-to-many relationship** by default, since it created that second column, which would allow the same parent in many child entries.

> Some may argue you could create a **unique index** for that second
>   column as FK to avoid having the same parent id, but EF6 doesn't work
>   this way (maybe they think it doesn't make sense doing this).

The first option you tried is the right way to configure a one-to-one relationship, and the `Id` in the `SystemConfiguration` is a PK and a FK to `BaseSystem` at the same time.

Comment: Your first sentence sums it all up (and you're correct about the one-to-many as well).  It was difficult to notice at first because, by convention, I am used to seeing a FK called Parent_Id.  It never occurred to me to use the ID as the FK in a one-to-one relationship.  So I redid everything and it's now configured as you stated.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I worked in a company where they used that `Parent_Id` convention as well, but I got in the same problem/doubt when started working with EF. That's why I soon understood your question, which was a nice one.