# Configuring relationship in C# code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api2

So I have these models:

ParentModel.cs

```
public class ParentModel {
  ...properties here

  //relationship to Child
  [ForeignKey("ChildModelID")]
  public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
}
```

ChildModel.cs

```
public class ChildModel{
  ...properties here

  //relationship to parent
  [ForeignKey("ParentModel")]
  public int? ParentModelID { get; set; }
  public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Web API Code-first. I am new to this. And I am getting the error below when the database is being created. But if I remove the navigation property in ParentModel (i.e. `public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }`) everything works fine, except that it doesn't fulfill my needs. I want to eager load (or lazy load not sure which term is right) the ChildModel when I get the ParentModel. The relationship here is Zero-or-One-to-One. Meaning the ChildModel can have a record that doesn't have a reference in ParentModel.

```
Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ChildModel_ParentModel_Source' in relationship 
'ChildModel_ParentModel'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key 
properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must 
be '*'.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how about remove [ForeignKey("ChildModelID")] from ParentModel?

Comment: Still the same, originally that code wasn't there but an answer online suggested it to me but still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF6 Foreign key with one-to-one relationship and two-way property navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515355/ef6-foreign-key-with-one-to-one-relationship-and-two-way-property-navigation)

Comment: How is deleting [ForeignKey("ChildModelID")] from ParentModel will not fufill your needs?

Comment: @AbdullahDibas removing it still give me the same error.

Comment: @MartinBäckström I didn't understood the answer there sorry. Can you elaborate and post an answer here? That would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Zero-or-One-to-One mean that there are ChildModel has null ParentModel? a child without parent? is this possible, reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

ChildModel and ParentModel is One-to-Zero/One

UPDATED:

So let try this code

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModel
{
    //[ForeignKey("ChildModel")]
    //[Key]
    public int ChildModelId { get; set; }
    public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ChildModel> ChildModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParentModel> ParentModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentModel>().HasKey(s => s.ChildModelId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentModel>().HasRequired(s => s.ChildModel).WithOptional(s => s.ParentModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The problem now is I can't insert a record in the ChildModel without the ParentModelID. Not even when I put the ff. code: 
`public int? ParentModelID { get; set; }`

Comment: Also if I remove the `[Key]` annotation it gives me the error I mentioned on my original question.

Comment: @Jed you want to insert a ChildModel without ParentModelID? A child without Parent?  is this reasonable? The question: ChildModel and ParentModel which is principal, which is dependent?

Comment: Yes I want to insert a child without a parent. It's unorthodox but reasonable on my case.

Comment: Yes that worked. But I didn't have to include the following line:
`modelBuilder.Entity<ParentModel>().HasKey(s => s.ChildModelId);`
since parent model didn't have the child model's id it's my child model that contains the parent model's id.

Comment: A new problem arose on this answer. I couldn't eager load the ChildModel when I query the ParentModel record.

Comment: I can do eager loading like this var parent = context.ParentModels.Include(s => s.ChildModel).FirstOrDefault(); with the above code. If you modified, I am not sure it work or not

Comment: Ah yeah the difference on your code is that you have the ChildModelId on the ParentModel, usually we don't put the ChildModelID on the parent model, it's usually the child model who has the ParentModelID, right?

Comment: @Jed "usually we don't put the ChildModelID on the parent model, it's usually the child model who has the ParentModelID, right?" you are right! However, you also specified that ChildModel and ParentModel is One-to-Zero/One. So the above code reflect correctly this relationship

Comment: If you read one of my comments it said that ChildModel and ParentModel is One-to-Zero/One is not reasonable. the correction is "parent one - child zero or one".

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the `ForeignKey` attribute. Shouldn't it be on `ParentModel` and refer to `ParentModelID`?

```
public class ChildModel
{
    ...properties here

    //relationship to parent
    public int? ParentModelID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentModelID")]
    public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah if you look at the code above, you'll notice I have the ForeignKey on both models.

Comment: No, you haven't. Look again at my answer. The attribute is on a different property